# rtrim <br /> when the last char is r

Tags: php, character

i have a problem with rtrim when the last character is r :

```
$str = 'En mille morceaux sur le sol<br/>Donc, je peux chasser les lucioles<br/>Je fais face à la douleur, c\'est magnifique<br/>Je ne dois plus courir<br/>Je ne dois plus courir<br /><br />';
$result = rtrim ($str, '<br />');

echo $result;
// En mille morceaux sur le sol<br/>Donc, je peux chasser les lucioles<br/>Je fais face à la douleur, c'est magnifique<br/>Je ne dois plus courir<br/>Je ne dois plus couri
```

so it misses the final r, thank's for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second argument to `rtrim` is not a substring. Rather, all combinations of the given characters are removed, regardless of their order.
For example,

```
$result = rtrim ($str, ' /<>br');
```

would give you the same result.
Because, starting from the end, characters are removed from the string until a character is encountered which is not in the given string.

Comment: ah yes .. I had not seen him like that, I used preg_replace then, thank you for help!